# Show app's notification settings in Settings app without requesting authorisation

Tags: ios, push-notification

It seems to be that the app's notifications settings are only available in the Settings app *after* the app has requested authorisation.

Is there a way for an app to have the "notification" section in the settings app without calling `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization`?

[image: screenshot of iOS settings app showing app's notification settings]

Comment: no you can't, everything must be approved

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It’s not that I want it to be turned on without user authorisation. I would just like the option to be available in the settings for the user to turn on notifications by themselves.

Comment: I understand what you want, but its not how iOS works. It only shows up as a setting, when it is something that has been authorised. These setting screens don't have an auth flow, they simply allow to turn on / off. You can't turn something on / off unless the user has granted permission to your app to allow the action in the first place. Your app will need to request authorisation.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put. No.

The TDLR here is that iOS mandates that before any settings are presented to a user, permission to access the folder/endpoints that the permission controls needs to be granted.